# How could I write PHP code into a file created by PHP?

Tags: php, html, fopen, fwrite, fgets

The title is self-explanatory. Within PHP, I create a PHP file, add some PHP and HTML code to it, then close it. The problem is that PHP files take all PHP code found and converts it to emptiness. Here's the last thing I tried.

```html
$phpfile=fopen('backupfile.php',"r");
$phptext=fgets($phpfile);
  if(stristr($link, 'http://') === FALSE) {
  fwrite($file2,$phptext."<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=http://".$link." '/>");


  }else{
  fwrite($file2,$phptext."<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=".$link." '/>");

  }
```

phpfile includes the following:

```
<?php $file=fopen("/num","r"); $bar=fgets($file); $bar=$bar+1; $file=fopen("/num","w"); fwrite($file,$bar); ?>
```

As said before, it simply doesn't add that to the file.

I tried htmlentities but that made the PHP code visible to the page and not hardwired into the file.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does it add standard ASCII text - as in - you KNOW that the writing process itself works, regardless of what the concent is?

Comment: Have you tried `$phptext."<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=http://'".$link."' '/>"`

Comment: @Joum I can't see any difference between that and what I wrote above.

Comment: You might just want to try `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`

Comment: Beware of writing systems that can write their own PHP code. The ability to do that makes for a very tempting target for hackers. There are good reasons for doing this, but if you do, it's worth also going that extra mile to make sure doubly your code is secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your code using only (escaped) single quotes. Using double quotes will cause the embedded php to be interpreted.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Its not really about writing code inside a file, you can bridge this idea using a Database.

You could have a standard directory set-up, ie: help documents.

Inside that directory, have a file: you can simply query the Database for pages, integrate a permalink to each page using a get value and then show content from that value (maybe a page ID).

Of-course, you'll need to implement standards and security - ie, if anyone can create pages - ensure only certain html can be added or BBCode.

I hope this widens your idea; this is how most forums, posts, comments ect.. work.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Code clarification:

```
$link = "some like address";
  if(mb_strpos($link, 'http://') === FALSE || mb_strpos($link, 'http://') > 0) {
     $link = "http://".$link;
   }
  $phptext = PHP_EOL."<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=".$link." '/>";
   file_put_contents('backupfile.php', $phptext, FILE_APPEND);
```

Ok so what did I do here:

- Checking with multibyte string checks if HTTP:// appears in the string, checking at the start is irrelivant because if it's not at the start it's an invalid HTTP request anyway, and you make no checks for this in the code provided.
- Once checked, the `$link` value is updated.
- Then use [file_put_content](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to append what is in the string into the existing file. If the file does not exist then it will be created.

---

Edit:

It is not clear from your question but if you want `$link` saved in the string then write the link as follows with single quotes:

```
$phptext = PHP_EOL.'<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=$link"/>';
```